# How can we avoid Review document and Signing completion popup when document send as email

Tags: docusignapi

How can we avoid Review document and  Signing completion popup when
document send as email  ?
I want to avoid unnecessary popup for simplified signer experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [New Signing Experience](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2F10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com%2FDocuSignSigningExperienceEnhancementsGuide.pdf&ei=fv5sVOSGLMOnyASGsIHICw&usg=AFQjCNHZL4rwQ6LREqiILJ5-lv3Dqi0ItQ&bvm=bv.80120444,d.aWw) that's being released to production Dec 5th?  The overall UI is simplified quite a bit.  You can switch your DEMO account to the New Signing Experiencing under Preferences -> Features -> Use DocuSign Winter ’15 Signing Experience Now.  After Dec 5th the same option should be available for Production.

Specifically I know the "Review Documents" screen is gone.  The Signing Complete is still there but is a little more fluid and doesn't "pop up".